# Wrong output on 'npm run prod'

Tags: css, laravel, sass, laravel-mix

I have this sass file with some variables that I'll use in my application, and I'm using Laravel Mix to compile them.

I'm putting all those variables in `:root` and this is the only styling in this element.

This is the faulty part:

```
--sg-card-produto-hover-bg: #c3c3c3;
--sg-card-produto-hover-box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
--sg-card-produto-hover-border-width: 2px;
--sg-card-produto-hover-border-style: solid;
--sg-card-produto-hover-border-color: var(--sg-cor-botao);
```

When I run `npm run dev`, or even `npm run watch`, it compiles just fine:

[image]

But when I run `npm run prod`, this is the result I'm getting (beautified):

[image]

Why is this happening?

I understand that it took the `border-width`, `border-style` and `border-color` parts of the variables and put them into a single property that is a reduced version of `border`, but they are **variables** and not properties!

Also, it didn't mix the variables in the part just above the previous code:

```
--sg-card-produto-bg: #d3d3d3;
--sg-card-produto-border-width: 2px
--sg-card-produto-border-style: solid;
--sg-card-produto-border-color: #222;
```

I believe this could be happening because of the introduced `var()` in `--sg-card-produto-hover-border-color`.

**Edit:**

It looks like `var()` is not the problem. I put a hex color and got the same result:

[image]

**Edit 2:**

I have renamed the variables as follows:

```
--sg-card-produto-hover-border_style: solid;
--sg-card-produto-hover-border_width: 2px;
--sg-card-produto-hover-border_color: var(--sg-cor-botao);
```

But now, the variables above this one (`--sg-card-produto-border...`) got mixed up instead:

[image]

It seems like the only the last ocurrences are being replaced.

**Edit 3:**

I noticed that it's mixing up only the last ocurrences of when it detects an expanded property.

So I used this quick fix:

```
--sg-card-produto-bg: #d3d3d3;
--sg-card-produto-border-width: 2px;
--sg-card-produto-border-style: solid;
--sg-card-produto-border-color: #222;

--sg-card-produto-hover-bg: #c3c3c3;
--sg-card-produto-hover-box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
--sg-card-produto-hover-border-style: solid;
--sg-card-produto-hover-border-width: 2px;
--sg-card-produto-hover-border-color: var(--sg-cor-botao);

border-style: none;
border-width: 0;
border-color: transparent;
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Weird, right?

Comment: If you remove the var() for an hex/color value it works?

Comment: It didn't work. I'll put the result in the question

Comment: I have opened an [issue on sass-loader GitHub](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/issues/550).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the minifier is naively converting `*border-*` properties to shorthand. You can sidestep the issue by using a different naming scheme (e.g. `--sg-card-produto-border-hover-color` instead of `--sg-card-produto-hover-border-color`)

Comment: Yeah that's what I did at first, then I added another rule as I put in the question.

Comment: Ah gotcha, in any case it is a bug in cssnano so [I opened an issue](https://github.com/ben-eb/cssnano/issues/450)